# If I get a book on Hibernate will that be useful for nHIbernate?

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate

Aside from the language used (Java, C#, etc.), are articles and books for Hibernate equally good for nHibernate?  Now that I am learning I want to research but I don't want to waste time on the wrong information.

Thank you.

I have a very basic CRUD database project for learning if anyone has any all in one article.

EDIT:  I bought the book nHibernate in Action, but I also found this website with helpful nHibernate videos:  http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would indeed, that said a friend of mine has just finished writing [NHibernate in Action](http://www.manning.com/kuate/) and I HIGHLY recommend it. As for web references I suggest the [best practices article by Billy MCatherty](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx), and of course the NHibernate documentation.

Comment: Only bad this is this book goes to 1.2 and nHibernate 2.0 has been out since August 2008. That's what I read anyway. For me it may be fine, though. Thank you again.

Comment: Not fully through it yet, so I can't comment. I do know its been through a series of revisions and not long since been sent to print, so this may not be the case any more. I'll get back to you with a definitive answer. Great resource anyway, I'm learning a lot more than I thought I would.

Comment: Oh, and I really wasn't just flippantly adding the comment about looking at the docs, they are a really dry read but very useful. Also I would suggest looking at the "Fluent NHibernate" project for building strongly typed mappings (and auto generation).

Comment: I bought the book. It is on the way February 2009 version. The sample chapter one was really nice.  I hope the rest of the book is that good.  Thanks.

Comment: The section on mappings was very useful to me. There's so many more options avaliable than I knew about.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. I would recommend you [Hibernate in Action](http://www.manning.com/bauer/).